# через jсуп не показывает кол-во игроков

Tags: java, jsoup

я указал все верно в jsoup, но у меня почему-то показываются версии и тд, а именно онлайн людей не показывается, что делать?

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class TestEpta {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://minecraft-statistic.net/ru/servers/")
                .userAgent("Chrome/4.0.249.0 Safari/532.5")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                .get();
Elements listNews = doc.select("#content > div > div.row > div.col-sm-8 > div:nth-child(2)");
        for (Element element : listNews.select("a"))
            System.out.println(element.text());System.out.println(listNews.select("a").get(2).text());
    }

}
```

Comment: Возможно, это число JS-ом грузится. В таком случае его через JSOUP не достать. Надо или Selenium подключать (долго, сложно) или отследить как на сайте это число получается и пробовать повторить запрос.

Comment: а как узнать, как это число получается на сайте?

Comment: Ну... Можно, например, вручную просмотреть тот HTML который вам JSOUP выдаёт. Если там нет нужных данных, то они получаются JS-ом.

Comment: @AXMEDJAN открыть DevTools в браузере, просмотреть какие запросы по сети ходят, какие обработчики на странице подключены, какой javascript-код выполняется и т.п.

Comment: а что это мне может дать? если на любом подобном мониторинг сайте, суп не показывает онлайн игроков, а если я прям дохожу до штучки показывающей онлайн то вылетает такая ошибка`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
 at TestAll.TestEpta.main(TestEpta.java:20)`